# Порядок передачи параметров в функцию

Tags: python-3.x, функции, передача-параметров

Почему в таком коде возникает ошибка

```
def (a,b, k=0,l)
```

но при этом если добавить *args

```
def (a,b, k=0,*args, l)
```

то ошибка исчезнет?

Comment: В первом случае l - недефлотный позиционный аргумент. Он должен следовать строго перед всех с дефолтом. А во втором это уже keyword only аргумент.  Он может идти после позиционных с дефолтом. *args как-бы дают понять интерпретатору, что дальше будут только аргументы по ключу. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters